# unable to connect to conatiner instances console web socket is closed or could not be opened

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I have deployed a docker image to an azure container instance.  i am attempting to access the container console via settings>containers>connect.

[image]

I receive the following error:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq0qP.jpg)

The following web socket error occurred: error: Web socket is closed or could not be opened... Please validate your network connection and retry the attempt.

I can successfully connect to my container via

> az container exec --resource-group myRG --name myContainer
>   --exec-command "/bin/bash"

Comment: What image do you use?

Comment: I anm using https://hub.docker.com/_/centos but have had similar issues with other images such as https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/

Comment: It works fine on my side, so I don't know what is the real problem. Can you share the steps you create the ACI?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, ended up being a corporate firewall issue, non-standard ports are blocked by default, included SSH ports.

At my company, might be different depending our your network.

Comment: The connection is not originating from OP network.

Comment: The web browser isn't connecting directly via azure, it still has to use your local connection if your on a VPN that will be the pipe, our workplace blocks pretty much all ports outside of 8080/80/443 I think, as soon as I dropped off the vpn I could both connect to the azure container running docker that was running a service and it responded as I expected, and I was able to SSH via the connect dialog. Was a lightbulb moment  so I had to have our security team open the port and it worked as expected on the VPN.

Comment: Yes, correct, I had a brain fart. Point is that websocket protocol uses TCP 80/443 outgoing to communicate, so that's usually open. Besides, the OP can browse the portal.azure.com so 443 outgoing should be open already (unless a firewall is blocking a specific range of IPs)

Comment: Once again unsure, but I had the exact error the OP had and I could not actually ping my docker instance running a service, until I dropped off my works VPN, everything else was correct. Not sure that's always the case, but I couldn't find any actual working answers, and this worked for me, It might help someone else, considering the OP asked this 2 years ago, I doubt they care any more.